# SPSS "No cases were input" warning - Is it possible to get a table with 0 counts?

Tags: spss

I am running a huge syntax, with lots of `CTABLES` and `FREQUENCIES` commands. Some of them have a filter:

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF [condition].
FREQUENCIES VAR1.
```

In some cases, this results in no cases being selected, so the output is just a warning text. Is it possible to still get a table with 0 counts...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all cases are screened out, a procedure never gets a chance to run.  However, suppose  you create one case with everything missing but a filter value of 1.  Then use CTABLES instead of FREQUENCIES and specify that empty categories should be shown (on the Categories subdialog if using the gui.)

If you want to make this perfectly accurate, create a weight variable with case 1 weighted by a very small value (1e-8, say), and all the other cases with a a weight of 1.